# Github Actions: Is there a way to run actions on Pull Requests opened from specific branches?

Tags: pull-request, github-actions

I'm trying to create an action whose workflow runs when Pull Requests from specific branches are opened against master. What I currently have runs the workflow on all Pull requests opened against master from all branches.

```yaml
name: Auto Approve Pull Request
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'master'
      - 'skip-*'

jobs:
  build:
    name: Approve PR
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fetch out code
        uses: username/my-github-repo@master
        with:
          token: ******
        env:
          BRANCH_PREFIX: "skip-*"
          PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH: "master"
```

I wanted to have the workflow to run on just branches named `skip-*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found was to use an if statement to check that the head-ref branch name matches (starts with) `skip-`.

Here's my solution:

```yaml
name: Auto Approve Pull Request
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'master'

jobs:
  build:
    name: Approve PR
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'skip-') == true
    steps:
      - name: Fetch out code
        uses: username/my-github-repo@master
        with:
          token: ******
        env:
          BRANCH_PREFIX: "skip-*"
          PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH: "master"
```

Notes:

> - Use the github context to find the branch name that's opening the Pull Request (https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context)
> - Github functions: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#startswith

Comment: Note that the workflow run will still show up in the repo's Actions page (with a grey "skipped" icon). Might be kind of annoying